# Windows kernel IRP hooking

Tags: usb, driver, hook, windows-kernel

Why am i only seeing `IRP_MJ_PNP` events upon plugging / unplugging / using various USB devices ?

The vast majority are some

`IRP_MJ_PNP - IRP_MN_QUERY_CAPABILITIES`

Using the tool from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1224222/Drivers-Dispatch-Routines-Hooking)

I am hooking these devices / drivers:

```
{
Reference count: 6
BLUETOOTH
DEVICE_SECURE_OPEN
Dispatch table: 1111111111111111111111111111
\Driver\BTHUSB

Reference count: 2
ACPI
DEVICE_SECURE_OPEN
Dispatch table: 1111111111111111111111111111
\Driver\RtkBtFilter

Reference count: 1
ACPI
DEVICE_SECURE_OPEN
Dispatch table: 1111111111111111111111111111
\Driver\ACPI

Reference count: 11
UNKNOWN
DEVICE_SECURE_OPEN
Dispatch table: 1111111111111111111111111111
\Driver\USBHUB3
\Device\USBPDO-3
}
Last error g: 0Last error h: 0Last error i: 01 : DEVICE LIST : STACK
{
Reference count: 4
UNKNOWN
DEVICE_SECURE_OPEN
Dispatch table: 1111111111111111111111111111
\Driver\USBHUB3

Reference count: 1
ACPI
DEVICE_SECURE_OPEN
Dispatch table: 1111111111111111111111111111
\Driver\ACPI

Reference count: 8
UNKNOWN
DEVICE_SECURE_OPEN
Dispatch table: 1111111111111111111111111111
\Driver\USBXHCI
\Device\USBPDO-0
}
Last error g: 0Last error h: 0Last error i: 02 : DEVICE LIST : STACK
{
Reference count: 4
UNKNOWN
DEVICE_SECURE_OPEN
Dispatch table: 1111111111111111111111111111
\Driver\USBXHCI
\Device\USBFDO-0

Reference count: 1
ACPI
DEVICE_SECURE_OPEN
Dispatch table: 1111111111111111111111111111
\Driver\ACPI

Reference count: 7
UNKNOWN
DEVICE_SECURE_OPEN
Dispatch table: 1111111111111111111111111111
\Driver\pci
\Device\NTPNP_PCI0003
}
```

Which are obtained by enumerating the first 4 parents of `GUID_CLASS_USB_DEVICE`

`Dispatch table: 1111111111111111111111111111` signifies that all of the 28 IRPs are marked for hooking.

Maybe there is some other tool for hooking IRPs that I can check against ?

Comment: Hi, Did you find an answer to the question?

Comment: @SaeedMasoomi i am afraid not, I gave up on that approach.